# "Command not found" when try to load daemon/agent programatically using system() function on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd

When I try to load some process behalf of another user I receive next error:

```
sudo: someusername: command not found
system result: 256
```

Please note that I run it from the process which is running under root.

Here is a code how I do:

```
        NSString *command = @"sudo someusername /bin/launchctl load -S Aqua /Library/LaunchAgents/com.agent.someagent.plist";
        int result = system([command UTF8String]);
        NSLog(@"system result: %d", result);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sudo -u someusername ...`?

Comment: When I user the command described above in terminal it is running correctly.
Anyway when I set -u, I receive another error: launch_msg(): Socket is not connected

Comment: So the `-u` flag is correct then.

Comment: Not really. I need to run the command above programatically because it works in terminal.

Comment: That exact command can't work in the terminal. The syntax is wrong.

Comment: You used to think `-u` is important (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137738/launching-command-using-nstask-returns-error) and the error you are getting now looks `launchd`-related which shows that you are invoking it at least.